# Show that $ \int_{S^2} (xy)^2\, dS = \frac{4\pi}{15}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, spherical-harmonics

I have been constructing some examples related to spherical harmonics.  I wanted to know the $L^2$ norm of the function $f(x,y,z) \in S^2 = \{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics) suggests this normalization:

$$ \int_{S^2} (xy)^2\, dS  = \frac{4\pi}{15}$$

Are there any derivations that do not involve [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)? I am hoping for a more algebraic derivation.  Maybe it will use spherical coordinates implicitly.

\begin{eqnarray*}
x &=& \cos \theta \cos \phi \\
y &=& \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
z &=& \sin \phi
\end{eqnarray*}

For smaller degree terms there is a trick.  I would do the integral of $1$:

$$ \lvert\lvert\,1 \,\rvert\rvert^2 = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{S^2} 1 \, dS   = 1$$

The averages of homogenous linear terms (or cubic terms) is zero.  Quadratics have a trick:

$$ \lvert\lvert\,x \,\rvert\rvert^2 = \lvert\lvert\,y \,\rvert\rvert^2 = \lvert\lvert\,z \,\rvert\rvert^2 = 
\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{S^2} x^2 \, dS   =
\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{S^2} (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \, dS   = \frac{1}{3}$$

I don't think there's such a trick for quadratic polynomials of 4th degree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through spherical coordinates or not,
$$ I(k)= \iint_{S^2}(xy)^{2k}\,d\mu $$
boils down to a value of Euler's Beta function. We have
$$ \iint_{x^2+y^2=R^2}(xy)^{2k}\,d\mu=R^{4k+1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\cos\theta\sin\theta\right)^{2k}\,d\theta =2\pi R^{4k+1}\cdot\frac{1}{4^{2k}}\binom{2k}{k}$$
hence $I(k)$ can be computed from Cavalieri's principle. Or

$$\begin{eqnarray*} I(k)&=&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(\theta)^{4k+1}\cos(\varphi)^{2k}\sin(\varphi)^{2k}\,d\theta\,d\varphi\\&=&2\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(2k+\tfrac{3}{2}\right)}=\color{red}{\frac{4\pi\binom{2k}{k}}{(4k+1)\binom{4k}{2k}}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: This looks like Crofton formula

Answer (score 2):

There is $x^2 y^2 + x^2 z^2 = x^2 (1 - x^2)$ and $dS = 2\pi dx$.

Comment: The second one is false as written. Once you integrate around the $x$ axis circle there will be a $2\pi$.

Comment: The second one refers to the fact that the area of $S^2$ between the planes $x=x_1$ and $x=x_2$ is equal to $2\pi|x_2 -x_1|$. The only remaining integral is along the x-axis.

Comment: That's fine. You exploited symmetry to obtain a function of $x$ alone. Then $ \int \int dS  = \int 2\pi dx$. Your math is cprrect, your writing is just a bit off. Really elegant use of symmetry though.

Comment: This could be the [washer method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution) from Calculus? This article on the [napkin ring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napkin_ring_problem) problem could be relevant. In any case I have $ \int \int dS  = \int 2\pi \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$